# Center text under image and use Jquery append

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'd like to create a series of images of fruits and vegetables and have the name of that fruit or vegetable to appear centered under the image. Then, I'd like to use Jquery append to make the names appear when a button is clicked

```
($(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });
```

Currently, I'm using the ul li so that the images appear one after a another in a gallery style. I'd also like for the images to be centered on the page.

Big thanks for any help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".applecontainer").click(function() {
    $(".applebag,.apple").fadeToggle();
  });
  $(".lemoncontainer").click(function() {
    $(".lemonbag,.lemon").fadeToggle();
  });
  $(".limecon").click(function() {
    $(".limebag,.lime").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.applebag {
  display: none;
}

.applecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.lemonbag {
  display: none;
}

.lemoncontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.limebag {
  display: none;
}

.limecon {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="applecontainer">
    <img class=apple src="apple.png" ;/>
    <img class=applebag src="applebag.png" ;/> apple
  </li>
  <li class="lemoncontainer">
    <img class=lemon src="lemon.png" ;/>
    <img class=lemonbag src="lemonbag.png" ;/>
  </li>
  <li class="limecon">
    <img class=lime src="lime.png" ;/>
    <img class=limebag src="limebag.png" ;/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your idea is clear... but how do you intend to place the clickable elements? I mean if you intend to place a clickable button for each fruit, that event would interfere with the clickable container ! So we put buttons outside of each container and when clicked it would display the image legend of that container?

Comment: So is it only one button that displays all fruit names... or a button for each fruit container?

Comment: You better explain to us more about the expected design in "non-technical words" ... Like what's going to load first (fruits images..), how many buttons do we see first?  Does the fruit container look empty at first, then we click to reveal it's content... is that mandatory? Because the way I see your script would act a bit weird after toggling :)

Comment: Hi @Bilel! I intend to place a button called "Names" at the top of the page under header. When someone clicks "names" all the names of the fruits and vegetable will appear under their respective images. As of right now, the fruit and vegetables appear and when you click on each fruit, it changes into the image of the method of storing that fruit or vegetable. I want too add the option of seeing the names of the fruits and vegetables just in case someone doesn't recognize a more obscure one.

Comment: @Bilel, this looks great, thank you. I will try it promptly. Is there a way to have the images appear horizontally one after another?

Comment: Sorry I'm using my phone now... It was a draft that Stackoverflow kept active... There were some small issue with Html nested tags that could be optimized. That's why I deleted it.. I'll bring it back when corrected if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed many things from your code... Maybe too much things *lol!* Anyway, take what is useful to you in all this.

Principal changes:

- I used some classes for "type" of element instead of specific class for each "fruit" That reduced a lot the CSS and the event handlers.
- I used CSS [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for centering elements.
- I used the fadeToggle callback to animate the images one after the other.
- I used the [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to determine the visible element.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".fruitcontainer").click(function () {
    let fruit = $(this).find(".fruit");
    let fruitbag = $(this).find(".fruitbag");

    if (fruit.is(":visible")) {
      fruit.fadeToggle(800, function () {
        fruitbag.each(function () {
          $(this).fadeToggle(800);
        });
      });
    } else {
      fruitbag.fadeToggle(800, function () {
        fruit.fadeToggle(800);
      });
    }
  });

  $("#showNames").click(function () {
    $(".fruitname").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}

.fruitbag,
.fruitname {
  display: none;
}
.fruitname {
  margin-bottom: -2em;
}
.fruitcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showNames">Names</button>
<ul>
  <li class="fruitcontainer">
    <img class="fruit" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=apple.png" />
    <img class="fruitbag" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=applebag.png" />
    <p class="fruitname">apple</p>
  </li>

  <li class="fruitcontainer">
    <img class="fruit" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=lemon.png" />
    <img class="fruitbag" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=lemonbag.png" />
    <p class="fruitname">lemon</p>
  </li>

  <li class="fruitcontainer">
    <img class="fruit" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=lime.png" />
    <img class="fruitbag" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=limebag.png" />
    <p class="fruitname">lime</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BaLQvJx)

Comment: Hi @Louys, this is jaw dropping and beautiful. Thank you! It's so much cleaner. I would love for the images to wrap and I tried to add "flex-flow: row wrap;" to the CSS of ul, but then it only shows one image per row. Do you know what change to make so that the images wrap according to the width of the browser window? Thank you from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: Try `flex-direction: column;` on the `ul`, ;)

Comment: I feel I'm missing something, @Louys. I wrote ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
} but I'm still getting only one image per line